# "Stucked": Is it correct?

Tags: tense

I've seen that both "stuck" and "stucked" are in use as verb 3. Am I right or is "stucked" just wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see "stucked"?

Comment: i got an email in which i saw a sentence "i was stucked in "xyz"  task."

Comment: Every dictionary gives you the thee base forms of irregular verbs.   http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stick_1?q=stick

Answer (score 21):

For most verbs, we form the simple past and the past participle by adding -ed to the verb, for example kick - kicked - kicked. Stick is irregular: the simple past and past participle are formed as follows: stick - stuck - stuck.

There is no "stucked". This kind of mistake is often made by English children. I imagine it is also common for people learning English as a second language.

Any good dictionary, for example the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick), will tell you the correct forms for the simple past and the past participle.